# Find the sum of the first n terms if a series is both geometric and arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

I have a simple series of the form:

$n+q(n-1)+q^2(n-2)+q^3(n-3)+q^4(n-4)...q^{n-1}$

Where $n$ is in the natural numbers, $q$ is a probability between $[0,1]$. I was wondering if there is some way to present this sum elegantly. I assume that two terms are needed.

I think this question is similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650149/combined-geometric-and-arithmetic-series-partial-sum) thread but not quite the same, I'm under the impression the answer is much more complicated...

Comment: Shouldn't the last term be $q^{n-1}$? Because the pattern goes like $n q^0 + (n-1) q^{1}+ \ldots + q^{n-1}(n-(n-1)) + q^n (n-n) $

Comment: @Ernie060 Yes sorry, corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F_n(q)=n+q(n-1)+\cdots +q^{n-1}$$

Note:  that's what I believe you intended.

Then $$F_n(q)-qF_n(q)=n-q-q^2-\cdots -q^n$$

Now, $$q+q^2+\cdots q^n=q\times (1+q+\cdots +q^{n-1})$$ and the term in parentheses is a standard Geometric Series.  Specifically, $$1+q+\cdots +q^{n-1}=\frac {q^n-1}{q-1}$$

It follows that $$F_n(q)=\frac 1{1-q}\times \left( n-q\times \frac {q^n-1}{q-1}\right)$$

Comment: Could you add some commentary about how you jumped to the last step?

Comment: @Dio I've added a little algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Another (and longer) approach: the series is equal to $n$ times a geometric series minus $q$ times a derived geometric series. One gets

$$n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k - q \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k q^{k-1}$$
$$= n \frac{1-q^n}{1-q} - q \frac{d}{dq} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q^k \right)$$
$$= n \frac{1-q^n}{1-q} - q \frac{1-nq^{n-1} - (n-1)q^{n}}{1-q}$$
$$=\frac{n}{1-q} + \frac{q(1-q^n)}{(1-q)^2} $$