# Is it possible to combine an arithmetic an geometric sequence, but first adding and then multiplying?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

[picture of solution for when you multiply first and add after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zagW8.png)

link of original discussion of the picture: [Combined geometric and arithmetic series partial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2650149/combined-geometric-and-arithmetic-series-partial-sum?answertab=active#tab-top)

In this picture, you can see a way of solving combined arithmetic and geometric sequence, however for this equation to work you need to multiply first and then add after. I want to be able to do it the other way around.

I know hoe to this somewhat by doing the following:

=((+)⋅+)⋅

You can just keep adding: {  ***⋅+)***  } to the equation to find the next term but this is still somewhat tedious, I want to find a way in which you can just find the nth term by plugging in its positional value into the equation. Meaning if I want to find the 5th term n=5 and so on.

- the nth term, for example, the 5th term of the sequence

- The original value, or the first value in the series

- the amount added every time

- the amount multiplied / common ration I think

If anybody knows how to do this that would be amazing Thank you!

Comment: Compare:
$$
a_{n+1} = qa_n + d
$$
$$
b_{n+1} = q(b_n+d) = q b_n + qd = qb_n + C
$$
You can just call $qd = C$ and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
a_n &= \bigg( \Bigl( \bigl( (a_1 + d) \cdot q + d \bigr) \cdot q + d \Bigr) \cdot q + d \bigg) \cdot q + \cdots \\
\\
&= \Bigl( \bigl( (a_1q + dq + d) \cdot q + d \bigr) \cdot q + d \Bigr) \cdot q + \cdots \\
\\
&= \bigl( (a_1q^2 + dq^2 + dq + d) \cdot q + d \bigr) \cdot q + \cdots \\
\\
&= (a_1q^3 + dq^3 + dq^2 + dq + d) \cdot q + \cdots \\
\\
& \;\; \vdots \\
\\
&= a_1q^{n-1} + dq^{n-1} + dq^{n-2} + \cdots + dq \\
\\
&= a_1q^{n-1} + dq \; (q^{n-2} + q^{n-3} + \cdots + 1) \\
\\
&= \boxed{ a_1q^{n-1} + dq \left( \frac{q^{n-1}-1}{q-1} \right) }
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I was confused at first but damn I get it now. Thank you!